# How to group the data properly by multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database table that represents concert hall and it looks as following:

Columns: `ActionID, RegionName, RowNumber, Price, Quantity`

The sample data:

```
ActionID RegionName   RowNumber   Price Quantity
1         Region1        22       8000    7
1         Region1         -       8000    1
1         Region2        10       5000    2
1         Region2        10       5000    2
1         Region2        10       5000    1
```

I should display particular regions with overall quantity per region grouped by ActionID, RegionName, Price and Quantity.

```
1   Region1   22   8000   8
1   Region2   10   5000   5
```

As you can see the `RowNumber` should be displayed, but not taken into account in grouping.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your result. There should be more than two rows if you group by 4 columns. I guess you dont want to include the Quantity in the group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `MAX` or `MIN` to collapse the rows:

```
SELECT MAX(ActionID), RegionName, MAX(RowNumber), MAX(Price), SUM(Quantity)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY RegionName
```

This obviously gets more complicated if you have multiple `ActionID` or `RowNumber` or `Price` per region. In that case, only use this if you don't care which one of these multiple values you get back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CTE and ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By ActionID, RegionName, Price
                                Order By RowNumber),
          OverallQuantity = SUM(Quantity) OVER (Partition By ActionID, RegionName, Price)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT ActionID, RegionName, RowNumber, Price, Quantity = OverallQuantity
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
ActionID    RegionName  RowNumber   Price   Quantity
1           Region1      -          8000      8
1           Region2      10         5000      5
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05c85/5/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT ActionId,
        RegionName, 
        MAX(RowNumber),
        MAX(Price), 
        SUM(Quantity)
FROM #tblTest
GROUP BY ActionId, RegionName
```

But if there are more RowNumber or Price, it should be modified the query